# Loop and object in Java

Tags: java

When I create several objects for my cars, I would like to enumerate my cars also...

For example:

```
----------------------
Car n ° **1**
Mark : Opel
Model : CDTI
Number of doors : 3
Price : 7000
----------------------
Car n ° **2**
Mark : Mercedes
Model : Classe A
Number of doors : 5
Price : 10000
----------------------
```

For now, I have this:

```
----------------------
Car n ° 
Mark : Opel
Model : CDTI
Number of doors : 3
Price : 7000
----------------------
Car n ° 
Mark : Mercedes
Model : Classe A
Number of doors : 5
Price : 10000
----------------------
Car n ° 
Mark : BMW
Model : Seie 5
Number of doors : 5
Price : 15000
```

In my class `Car`, I don't understand how to create this loop ???

I tried this, but it's not correct

```java
public void display() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        i++;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Car n ° " + i);
    System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
    System.out.println("Model : " + model);
    System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
    System.out.println("Price : " + price);
}
```

Here is my class `Car`

```java
public class Car {

    public String mark;
    public String model;
    public int nbDoors;
    public int price;

    public Car(String mark, String model, int nbDoors, int price) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.nbDoors = nbDoors;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Car n ° ");
        System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
        System.out.println("Model : " + model);
        System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
        System.out.println("Price : " + price);
    }
}
```

Here is also my class `Main`

```java
System.out.println("----------------------");
Car car1 = new Car("Opel", "CDTI", 3, 7000);
car1.display();
System.out.println("----------------------");
Car car2 = new Car("Mercedes", "Classe A", 5, 10000);
car2.display();
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to add an identifier where you can store the number. Otherwise you could pass the identifier as well.

Comment: include all your `System.out.println` inside your `while` loop, not outside.

Comment: You can add your cars to an array and loop over the array. Also, delete this line from the `display()` method and add it as an instruction in the loop, so that the loop looks something like this:
```
for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Car n ° " + (i + 1));
  car[i].display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the Collections, you should consider using an ArrayList rather than an array. That way you don't have to know how many cars will be in the array, or create the cars in advance like you do with an array.

The loop part is a simple for each loop that loops through the collection:

EDIT: Added a counter so each car receives an index. This also required the `.display()` method to change to receive the index.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(new Car("Opel", "CDTI", 3, 7000));
    cars.add(new Car("Mercedes", "Classe A", 5, 10000));
    int counter = 0;
    for(Car car : cars) {
        car.display(counter++);
    }
}
```

Here is a working sample: https://replit.com/@randycasburn/scratch-java

Comment: Thank you Randy, in display(), do you change something?

Comment: Didn't change a thing. Just implemented the car class by c-n-p. You can see the entire solution at the link I provided.

Comment: @eric - I personally wouldn't produce the output with a `display()` method. I would just override the `.toString()` myself, unless you have a different purpose for `.toString()`. (or that is part of the assignment ;-) )

Comment: It's not correct... I don't see the count in the print `Car n ° 
Mark : Opel ... ` normally I have to see `Car n ° 1
Mark : Opel ...`

Comment: how would you print it? It's just a free exercise...

Comment: if you only want a number appended, I've applied that solution in my edit. I also created a different [example here](https://replit.com/@randycasburn/scratch-java). If you want each Car to retain a unique identifier, you'll need to edit your Car class to include that. So I assumed you just wanted an index appended.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you a lot Randy for your help, it's ok now. Thank you for your explanation and your help. ^^

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making an array of cars in your main method:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car a = ...;
    Car b = ...;
    ...; //initialize all cars

    Car[] cars = {
        a,
        b,
        ...
    };
    for (int i = 1; i <= cars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        cars[i-1].display(i);
    }
}
```

And your display function in your car class could be changed slightly to this as @flaxel wrote:

```java
public void display(int number) {
    System.out.println("Car n ° " + number);
    System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
    System.out.println("Model : " + model);
    System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
    System.out.println("Price : " + price);
}
```

Comment: @JayC667 - its a good concept, but how many variables in the form of `Car a = ...` does the OP create? Does the OP have to know how many cars will be created in advance? The answer with arrays is _yes_ - the entire reason the Collections were created is in this use case.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yeah I know. But this was nontheless the first answer that solved the problem. The other posts were all pointing the wrong directions. Your post came an hour later. BTW: your code is also not clean. Having a for-each loop with a (loop-)external counter is never a good idea. Should have used a classic index-based for loop, keep the variables in the scope. Also, passing the counter into the display() method can be done but beats the separation of concerns. So in terms of cleanliness, this one still wins, even tho it's also lacking. Funny to see how many posts are completely off tho

Comment: @JayC667 - I agree with the counter thing and the display thing. We both know in the real world the Car class is going to be indexed _if that is really a requirement_. Otherwise this is just an exercise that exists outside the real world - like so many on SO :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this wrong

```
public void display(){
int i=0;
while(i < 10){
  i++;
}
System.out.println("Car n ° " + i);
System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
System.out.println("Model : " + model);
System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
System.out.println("Price : " + price);
}
```

it should be:

```
public void display(){
int i=0;
while(i < 10){
  i++;
System.out.println("Car n ° " + i);
System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
System.out.println("Model : " + model);
System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
System.out.println("Price : " + price);
}
}
```

Comment: so now the bracket it not in the wrong place but completely missing... is this considered an upgrade or a downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using a static `counter` and instance `id` field in `Car` class, and displaying the `id` field in `display` method:

```java
public class Car {

    private static int counter = 0;

    private int id = ++counter;  // id start from 1

    public String mark;
    public String model;
    public int nbDoors;
    public int price;

    public Car(String mark, String model, int nbDoors, int price) {
        this.mark = mark;
        this.model = model;
        this.nbDoors = nbDoors;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Car n ° " + id);
        System.out.println("Mark : " + mark);
        System.out.println("Model : " + model);
        System.out.println("Number of doors : " + nbDoors);
        System.out.println("Price : " + price);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is done properly, but not solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @JayC667, I don't think that the actual problem is _to use a loop in `Car` class_, it's rather _When I create several objects for my cars, I would like to enumerate my cars also._

Comment: True. And your solution in itself is pretty good. But the point of the question was how to iterate over the created cars. And even though you did some real fine post there, it did not address that central question. You should have added a main method with some list or array of cars, iterate over that. That's what was missing here.